# Replace character in numpy ndarray (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a **numpy ndarray** with 6 elements:

`['\tblah blah' '"""123' 'blah' '"""' '\t456' '78\t9']`

I am trying to **replace all tab characters `\t` with 4 spaces each** so that the numpy array would now be:

`['    blah blah' '"""123' 'blah' '"""' '    456' '78   9']`

I have considered **re.sub** but cannot figure out how to implement it when it comes down to an numpy ndarray. Any suggestions/help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`NumPy's core.defchararray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html) that deals with string related operations and for this case use [`replace` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.replace.html#numpy.core.defchararray.replace), like so -

```
np.core.defchararray.replace(arr,'\t', '    ')
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: arr
Out[44]: 
array(['\tblah blah', '"""123', 'blah', '"""', '\t456', '78\t9'], 
      dtype='|S10')

In [45]: np.core.defchararray.replace(arr,'\t', '    ')
Out[45]: 
array(['    blah blah', '"""123', 'blah', '"""', '    456', '78    9'], 
      dtype='|S13')
```

Comment: Quick follow-up; is it possible to get the number of the replacements, i.e. in this case 3?

Comment: @nk-fford One solution to that would be : `np.core.defchararray.not_equal(output, arr).sum()`.

Comment: Confused with what the `output` and `arr` is in this case? Could give a one-liner to explain how this count works please?

Comment: @nk-fford `output` would be the output from `np.core.defchararray.replace(arr,'\t', '    ')`? Basically we are counting the occurences where changes were made by the `replace` method.

Comment: I see, I was doing everything in one line and got confused. Thanks