# Reading list in from a text file

Tags: python, numpy

I currently have a text file containing data like so

```
0
0
0
1
0
1
5...
```

I'm struggling to read the file in as a list `[0,0,0,1,0,5...]` or as a numpy array. These txt files are around 400 lines of data. using the `f.readlines()` function is currently giving me a list that looks like `['0/n','0/n','0/n','1/n','0/n','5/n'...]`. if anyone knows a good way of doing this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Comment: What about numpy.genfromtxt?

Answer (score 0):

get the line content with f.readline() but while inserting the content into your list, exclude the last character as that is a new line character. 
Assuming you are working with python do something like this

```
x[i] = f.readline()[:-1]
```

where x is the name of your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run a replace to remove the escape characters:

```
np.core.defchararray.replace(arr,'\n', '    ')
```

where arr is the array from which you want to remove the escape characters. [Check also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957764/replace-character-in-numpy-ndarray-python)

Or you can have a quick look [here](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-read-file-with-python.cfm)

You may also use:

```
for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an array with newline characters, you can replace them as follows:

```
> a = ['0/n','0/n','0/n','1/n','0/n','5/n'] r = map(lambda x:
> x.replace('/n', ''), a) print(list(r))
```

This prints

> [0,0,0,1,0,5]

But I don't find the approach elegant.  Has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast from string to int with `astype`

```
num_list = np.array(list_with_endlines).astype(np.int64))
```